# Riverpod - read providers on api callback

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In the splash screen of my app, I make an api call and I want to save the response in a provider.

On initState I make this call:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getAllSchools();
      getAllShuls();
    });
}
```

Here is my getAllSchools() method:

```
  Future<void> getAllSchools() async {
    GetAllSchoolsApi getAllSchoolsApi = GetAllSchoolsApi();
    List<School>? schoolsList = await getAllSchoolsApi.getAllSchoolsApi(ref);
    ref.read(schoolListProvider.notifier).state = schoolsList ?? [];
  }
```

The api call works fine, and returns a list of schools. But this line causes an error

```
ref.read(schoolListProvider.notifier).state = schoolsList ?? [];
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (18329): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (18329): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Comment: Are you pushing to another screen after some seconds?

Comment: Because it seems that the BuildContext `(ref)` you are using is associated with the splash screen, and it's possible that the splash screen is getting disposed before the getAllSchools function finishes executing.

Comment: Thanks,. Indeed I was navigating to another page before the result came in.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in another way .
Define the  **schoolListProvider** in SplashScreen and watch it like this in ***build*** .

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.watch(schoolListProvider);
    return Container();
   }
```

**Now**, Define your **schoolListProvider** class like this .

```
class SchoolList extends LoadingChangeNotifier {
  ProfileState({required this.auth}) : super(loading: false);
  Auth auth;

  mutate(BuildContext context
      {Function(SchoolList response)? onSuccess,
      Function(DioError e)? onError}) async {
    try {
      startLoading();

      final response = await NetworkClient.request(
          '/schoolList', auth.token,
          data: data, options: Options(method: 'GET'));
      final schoolListResponse = SchoolListResponse.fromJson(response.data);

      if (schoolListResponse.data!.user!.firstName != null &&
          schoolListResponse.data!.user != null) {
        auth.user = schoolListResponse.data!.user!;
        auth.firstName = schoolListResponse.data!.user!.firstName; 
      }

      if (onSuccess != null) {
      
        onSuccess(schoolResponse);
      }
  
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      NetworkClient.onError(e, context);
      if (onError != null) {
        onError(e);
      }
    } finally {
      stopLoading();
    }
  }
}

final schoolListProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<SchoolState>(((ref) {
  //final auth = ref.read(authProvider);
  //return SchoolState(auth: auth);
  return SchoolState();
}));
```

*Then, call this provider anywhere you want to get the schoolList and details* .